# Skip link cutting off top of header across website

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I'm trying to implement a skip link on a site with a fixed header. Whenever I activate the skip link (using an anchor link), the top of the page then gets cut off.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

This is happening across the site, wherever the ID main-content has been indicated.

I have considered adding the anchor to a span element, but this would go against best practices and be unhelpful for screen reader users. I also don't think this would resolve the issue.

I have tried adding padding and margins to the ID, but with no luck.

Here's the HTML in the theme file:

```
<a href="#main-content" class="button button--skip-link">Skip to main content</a>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.button--skip-link:not(:focus):not(:hover) {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-4em);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-4em);
    transform: translateY(-4em);
    opacity: 0;
}

button:focus, 
.button:focus {
    border-color: #062434;
}

button:hover, button:focus, 
.button:hover, .button:focus {
    background-color: #08364E;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.button--skip-link {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 20;
    left: 0;
    right: 125em;
    top: 1em;
    width: 10em;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

I expect the Skip Link to bring the anchor link into focus (as it does). But I also expect the top of the header to not be cut off when the Skip Link has been activated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Stephanie! 

It is almost always helpful to provide a running example of your problem. To help us help you, could you please consider putting your code in a site that can run it like jsfiddle.net, codepen.io or jsbin.com?

Comment: I definitely have the same problem! I think the solution is actually controlling your skiplink and make it scroll to the appropriate area using JS but still keeping the href attribute there as fallback.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get much clearer what you're trying to achieve, but from what I got, see if that's what you're wondering to happen :

```css
#header {
  position: fixed;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <a href="#red">Click here to go to red and jump blue</a>
</div>
<br><br>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="red"></div>
```

Comment: So is this an answer or just trying to reproduce her problem?  Try adding some text in your red and blue boxes then you can see what’s she’s talking about

Answer (score 0):

## Make the skip link always visible. Do not be ashamed of being accessible.

Your skip link is hidden. It will have no utility for a vast majority of users who want direct visual access to that information *(without having to focus the link)*

- using touch screen (smartphone),
- eye tracking devices,
- screen magnifiers,
- people with physical disabilities who have difficulty to use a mouse
- voice recognition....

Screen reader users will ear something they can't view on the screen; because screenreader users are not all blind : people with  cognitive disabilities  (post stroke disorders for instance like aphasia), illiterate, non-native speakers, ...